# this file change its name every second :

Tags: files, tmp, png

```
tmp/systray_WXh70Y
tmp/systray_k4M7n1
tmp/systray_sqBFYf
```

one file in tmp folder change its name every second. 
it is valid file or not.

Comment: what process is creating those files and if that process is legal then it's ok

Comment: Looks like a system tray program